# Are industry related questions acceptable?

Tags: discussion, scope

I was looking at [this question on Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/466675/how-to-calculate-blending-for-a-plant-using-rosa) which looks very much like a "trying to find an easy solution by someone else and take the credit at work" kind of thing. I personally think that this kind of question should not be allowed on the site but I looked at the ["Tour"](https://stackexchange.com/tour) and ["About"](https://stackexchange.com/about)  pages of SE (I was trying to find something similar to the Homework question policy) and did not find this to be against the philosophy of the site. So my question is:

What is the policy of Physics SE on industry/work related questions?

Comment: Oh my. *"Is there any formula?"* is not exactly the kind of question someone (who should be) tasked with this sort of thing asks. It's not even the kind of question that student who is adequately prepared for advanced classwork asks.

Comment: Jeez, I would not want to drink water produced by that plant. But more generally, it's absolutely okay for people to use the SE network to help with their jobs. That's basically the core function of StackOverflow.

Comment: @knzhou thank you for the clarification, I had thought it was not okay in general... Now I just think it's wrong in particular.

Comment: @dmckee I agree with your point of view, that's why I thought of the homework policy, it seemed like the OP had made very little effort.

Comment: The homework policy is in effect for a different, practical reason, which is that answering homework freely would attract tons of low-quality questions that would choke the site. It doesn't mean we're against people receiving benefit from the site for their courses or jobs; I get such benefits all the time! Meanwhile, the particular post you linked is downvoted and closed, so what's the problem?

Comment: @knzhou FWIW this question [was asked](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/11157/timeline) *before* that post [was closed](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/466675/timeline). And I believe a majority of the downvotes came in later.

Comment: It is as @Blue says. I was the first to downvote the question, but I was uncertain wether I should flag it or not, that is why I came here to ask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your direct question:

> What is the policy of Physics SE on industry/work related questions?

We don't really have one. The fact that a question was inspired by a situation at someone's job shouldn't really have any bearing on how it's received here.

The specific question that you linked to probably has some issues which are unrelated to whether it came out of a real work situation.